# Retriving all the messages in gmail using gmail4j and javamail

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I have two issues and they are very related.

1. I can access my gmail inbox account using gmail4j, however when I create a Folder of messages, it only retrieves the emails that were sent to me. It never shows the emails I replied back to. Like, I have one multi-email, where 5 emails were sent to me but there were 2 that I replied back to. I can see the 5 emails perfectly but cannot see the 2 emails.
2. In my Sent mail, same issue; I can retrieve all emails I sent but not the ones that were replied back.

Is there any method specifically in Javamail that allows me to bypass this? I've been looking at the Message class and Folder class but can't find anything!

Edit: I'll try to clear it up. Let's say I was emailing Person B. B emails me first, so it is in my inbox. Then I send a reply back. In the inbox of Gmail, both emails joined together in a conversation (since sender and subject is the same). However, with javamail, I can only see the first email (that B sent) in my inbox while my reply back is in my sent box. Is there anyway I can gather both of these emails together as a conversation?

I need all the emails sent by me as well as any that were replied to and while I have all the emails sent by me, I can't seem to get all the emails that were replied to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the original messages, to which you replied?  Or are you looking for the reply messages that you sent?  The original messages will still be in one of your mailboxes unless you deleted them.  Perhaps you moved them out of your INBOX to another mailbox?  The replies you sent should be in the Sent mailbox.

Note that Gmail doesn't really have "mailboxes" in the IMAP sense.  Gmail tags look like IMAP mailboxes.

Comment: I ended up editing my issue with a scenario. I would appreciate it if you could help me out! Thank you!

Comment: If all you want is to use the Gmail conversation, see the [GmailMessage.getThrId](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/GmailMessage.html#getThrId()) method.  You need to use the JavaMail ["gimap" provider](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html).  You'll probably want to look for messages in the "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I needed but luckily, it was fine for me to get all the inbox and sent mail messages so that worked out! Thank you though!

Comment: Quick question, is there any reason why I can't retrieve the content of some emails (content = null) but when I view the emails in Gmail, there is actual content for the email? I was using getText from the JavaMail FAQ but that didn't help ...

Comment: Need more details to debug it.  What does the protocol trace show? Does the msgshow.java demo program work?

Comment: ImapGmailLabel.INBOX.getName() to open up the folder in the store and then Message[] messages = folder.getMessages() to retrieve the messages. When I do message[#].getContent() it returns null but when I view the actual email, there is content in the email. I can try msgshow.java.

Comment: Huh, I tried using msgshow.java and it somehow was able to print out the contents of my email. I guess there's something wrong with the way I'm extracting the contents of a message. Thank you for writing the msgshow.java!